# Message Logging - Storing Heroku Rails App in AWS Buckets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, amazon-s3

I have an app hosted on Heroku, and I'm looking to log the application messages directly to AWS buckets. My understanding is that doing this by accessing the file for every message is going to be very costly (plus the network overhead), so I'm wondering if anyone has experience/strategy to get this to work without incurring a large cost.
    I'm hoping to set it up so that I can rotate the logs by day.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier for you to just add specific addon for logging on Heroku. Have a look at some options https://elements.heroku.com/addons. You can set log rotation there and you don't have to configure anything or write any code.